# QGIS Client/Server

Tags: server, desktop-gis

Member of an IT team here. I have an employee who has asked me to assist them with the installation and setup of QGIS. The user typically uses QGIS on their home PC but would now like to use it for some business requirements. I noticed that there is a Desktop and Server version. While the user is only currently requesting the desktop version, I am curious to find out what the server version is for. Can someone give me a TL;DR: of the dichotomy of desktop versus server?

Comment: Simply put, QGIS Server is used to publish Data into the Internet while QGIS Desktop is used to work with spatial data on your PC. For Setting up QGIS Desktop I suggest OSGeo4W. Also check if the employe needs a spatial DB such as PostGIS.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS server is a geographic data server that work in conjunction with a web server to distribute data while QGIS desktop is a desktop software that let you create, edit, visualise and analyse geographic data on a computer.

Basically if you want to create a web GIS you will need QGIS server (or another geodata server) if you want to work with geographic data you will need QGIS desktop (or any other GIS software)

[QGIS Desktop user guide](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/index.html)

[QGIS server guide/manual](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/server_manual/index.html)

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Sounds like my end user only needs the desktop version then. This really helps. Thanks again!